# Options with Rails for triggering an email to all (or some) users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, actionmailer

Newb question: We've got a live site with registered users. Some new functionality has been added (including support for Mailers). We would like to trigger an email to all existing users (similar but not identical to one that will now automatically go out to new users).

What options do we have for triggering the sending of that email? This message will likely only be sent once so we don't need the code (other than the message itself) in the Rails app. Nor do we really need to store who received it because it will be assumed that all users have received such a message once we can get this one out.

I'm thinking Rake task but all the examples I seem to be able to find are for build script?!? Or should we just use the Rails console in `production`? Perhaps get an array of all `users` we want to send email to and then `deliver` message to them?

Not sure. I haven't worked with **ActionMailer** much.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it like this:

In order to determine if the system has sent an email to a user, you should add an attribute let's say 'sent_email' which is basically just a boolean.

I'd create a cron job for a rake task that checks all users with sent_email=0. Then, I'll loop through each array and send the email and set sent_email=1. The cron job can be run daily, depending on your preference. You can use whenever gem to setup the cron job.

schedule.rb (whenever stuff)

```
job_type :run_script, "RAILS_ENV=:environment ruby :path/script/:task"
every 1.day do
  run_script('send_email.rb')
end
```

script/send_email.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "Loading rails environment..."
require(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment") unless defined?(Rails)

class SendEmail
  def send_email
     users = User.send_email_to
     users.each do |user|
       OneTimeMailer.deliver_one_time_email(user)
     end
  end
end
```

mailers/one_time_mailer.rb

```
class OneTimeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def one_time_email(user)
    recipients user.email
    from 'your system'
    subject 'hello world'
    body 'this is a one time email. thank you'
  end
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! Two questions though. Because I only need to do this ONCE, do I really need a cron job running *every* day into the future? Second, this looks like it might be more appropriate for Rails 2? Not sure, but I think, at least the `deliver` method has changed in Rails 3?  Really looking for a simple **Rake** task if that's possible/appropriate for what I'm doing..

Comment: 1) If it's just once, scrap the cron job section of my comment and just run a rake task using the SendEmail class. 

2) I did a quick google and found this: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html. You can easily see what you need there. It will be something like OneTimeMailer.one_time_email(user).deliver

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing a rake task, run it once and you are done.

```
rails g task my_namespace my_task1 my_task2
```

Now you loop through your database:

```
namespace :sent_email_to_everyone do
  desc "TODO"
  task send_that_mail: :environment do
     user = User.all
     user.each do |user|
        Yourmailer.send_email(user.email)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you just run it and done

```
rake sent_that_mail
```